# How to get the Facebook iFrame Tab url (including parameters) from within the app?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I think there are a few similar questions that seem to suggest using `app_data` in the signed request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) but I'm not sure if it will be possible to do what I am trying to achieve with it as I've never used it before.

If I have my Facebook 'Tab' Url as follows:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_TITLE/PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID
```

What I want to do is add an extra parameter on the end as follows:

```
&WT.mc_id=email-uk-8014
```

The reason for this is for tracking purposes and links will be sent out of the form

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_TITLE/PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID&WT.mc_id=email-uk-8014
```

and the extra parameter will allow us to track the campaign id.

As you can see I have no way of knowing the value of the parameter beforehand as it depends on the link clicked by the user so is it possible to somehow get the value of the `WT.mc_id` parameter inside my iframe app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app_data` is the only parameter passed through other than the page ID and user's basic details (locale and if they do/don't like the page) - you'll need to use that for any sort of campaign tracking (or link elsewhere and redirect to the tab after capturing your analytics data)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass get variables in facebook but only in canvas application 
you just have to use $_REQUEST['xxx'] to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

you should not pass the param in href of facebook. Instead just make linking inside your app so that you can track the events. As you will be in iframe and having complete control you can do same on your own site.